# Loop through each pixel in a multiband raster in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy

I have a multiband raster having 23 bands for example. I am reading the raster using GDAL and converting it to numpy array. In numpy when I am checking the array shape it is showing as `23,4,5 i.e. 23 = bands, 4 = row and 5 = col`. I want to loop through each pixel in a manner that I am able to get the vector/array of all 23 values related to one pixel.

I am explaining it further in detail by example...

```
Band 1
    [[1,    2,   3,   4,  5],
     [6,    7,   8,   9,  10],
     [11,   12,  13,  14, 15],
     [16,   17,  18,  19, 20]]
Band 2
    [[21,   22,   23,   24,  25],
     [26,   27,   28,   29,  30],
     [31,   32,   33,   34,  35],
     [36,   37,   38,   39,  40]]
Band 3
    [[31,   32,   33,   34,  35],
     [36,   37,   38,   39,  40],
     [41,   42,   43,   44,  45],
     [46,   47,   48,   49,  50]]
Band 4
    [[41,   42,   43,   44,  45],
     [46,   47,   48,   49,  50],
     [51,   52,   53,   54,  55],
     [56,   57,   58,   59,  60]]
```

Now I want to loop through all bands in such a way that I should get array of values `[1,21,31,41] in first iteration and [2,22,32,42] in second iteration` and so on. I can do that in R using the pointer math and extract function easily but in python I am not able to do that because I have very less experience with looping and array indexing in python.

I have tried  some codes given on the StackOverflow

```
 for cell in arr:
     print cell

 for cell in arr.flat:
     print cell

 for row in arr:
    for cell in row:
         print cell

 for (i,row) in enumerate(arr):
     for (j,value) in enumerate(row):
         print value
```

The output I am getting is not as required.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, there is a more efficient way. Look at the numpy indexing docs, numpy.reshape, etc. Normally you should be able to vectorize the calculation and avoid most loops. If you give us more details about what is happening in the loops, we can point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i see it what you need is to have pixel values of same `index` grouped together. For grouping together same index e use `zip` here since the `bandx` itself is not flat we may first `flatten` then band and then do `zip` on the flattend bands

Here is example with 3 bands

```
band1 = np.array( [[1,    2,   3,   4,  5],
     [6,    7,   8,   9,  10],
     [11,   12,  13,  14, 15],
     [16,   17,  18,  19, 20]])
band2 = np.array([[21,   22,   23,   24,  25],
     [26,   27,   28,   29,  30],
     [31,   32,   33,   34,  35],
     [36,   37,   38,   39,  40]])
band3 = np.array([[31,   32,   33,   34,  35],
     [36,   37,   38,   39,  40],
     [41,   42,   43,   44,  45],
     [46,   47,   48,   49,  50]])
arr = [band1,band2,band3]
```

Following will give you array of `tuples` as you expected

```
zip(*map(lambda x:x.flatten(),arr))
```

If the bands are not `numpy` arrays but normal python arrays ,you may do the following

```
zip(*map(lambda x:x.flatten(),np.array(arr)))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  Yes u understood correctly I need pixel value of same index. I need more clarification. Actually I have 23 bands. Do I need to convert each band separately as np array. currently I am using following code to read raster and converting raster to numpy array.    from osgeo import gdal
>>> import numpy as np
>>> infile = "F:/PHD_work/peak_modification/test.img"
>>> data = gdal.Open(infile)
>>> arr = data.ReadAsArray()

Comment: What is the type of the band now. Iassumed them to be numpy array as there was a tag for numpy

Comment: you may make np.array out of result from `ReadAsArray` . Here I updated the answer

Comment: yes bands are numpy array.... I have mentioned the code I am using to convert all 23 bands as numpy array from raster. can u explain how I can pass all 23 bands in ur code zip(*map(lambda x:x.flatten(),[band1,band2,band3])):, do I have to pass each band manually as u mentioned...

Comment: if bands are numpy array the single line at the end would work.ie, the zip would work

Comment: ok I think i have to pass my array like this   zip(*map(lambda x:x.flatten(),[arr])) arr is my array

Comment: `zip(*map(lambda x:x.flatten(),arr))`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is using [`np.nditer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nditer.html):

```
>>> for i in np.nditer((Band1, Band2, Band3, Band4)):
...     print(i)
```

This prints

```
(array(1), array(21), array(31), array(41))
(array(2), array(22), array(32), array(42))
(array(3), array(23), array(33), array(43))
(array(4), array(24), array(34), array(44))
(array(5), array(25), array(35), array(45))
(array(6), array(26), array(36), array(46))
(array(7), array(27), array(37), array(47))
(array(8), array(28), array(38), array(48))
(array(9), array(29), array(39), array(49))
(array(10), array(30), array(40), array(50))
(array(11), array(31), array(41), array(51))
(array(12), array(32), array(42), array(52))
(array(13), array(33), array(43), array(53))
(array(14), array(34), array(44), array(54))
(array(15), array(35), array(45), array(55))
(array(16), array(36), array(46), array(56))
(array(17), array(37), array(47), array(57))
(array(18), array(38), array(48), array(58))
(array(19), array(39), array(49), array(59))
(array(20), array(40), array(50), array(60))
```

Even though it seems strange that this returns arrays actually makes it a really cool feature because these are views of the original array so you don't have the overhead of unpacking the value as python type and these zero-dimensional arrays behave (almost) like native python types.

Comment: i[0]  results in array(1, dtype=uint16)  ;int(i[0]) gives us 1